# What are roach motels (the insect trap) called in Australian English?

Tags: australian-english

In Australian English, what are the insect trap known as "roach motels" called? [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/roach_motel) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roach_Motel_(insect_trap)) (also [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roach_bait)) don't mention what it's called in Australian English.

Comment: Roach Motel is a brand name.  The generic term is glue trap or X bait trap, where X describes either the bait material or type of pest the bait is intended to attract.  Roach Motel might be a little like Kleenex in terms of being applied generically.  Are you asking about the trademark name Black Flag sells their product under in Australia, the generic term used in Australian English for a glue trap, or whether some other trademark or popular name is used generically in Australia?

Answer (score 1):

I'm an Aussie and I have never heard of a "roach motel" or of any other term for an insect trap of that nature. I have never seen them in hardware stores.

Having said that though, I do live in Hobart, the capital city of the island state of Tasmania, and Australia's coolest and most southerly city. We hardly get any cockroaches here. I think them in greater numbers in more northerly parts of our big country including Sydney and Brisbane.

Comment: There's lots of supposed sittings of cockroaches in Tasmania, but funnily enough no photographic proof! :)

Comment: "Sittings"? Do you mean "sightings"?